# wpf virtualizingstackpanel different behavior on different Win10 machines

Tags: c#, wpf, virtualizingstackpanel

My WPF application is using VirtualizingStackPanel for ListView. Scrolling this list is working fine on two different machines: my host machine (Windows 10 v1803 build 17134.228)  and one virtual machine (Windows 10 v1607 build 14393.2312 ). If I run the same application, exact the same copy, on my other VM (Windows 10 v1803 build 17134.165), the list doesn’t scroll smooth – it’s very slow. Short scroll steps about couple of lines is fine (CacheLength), but scrolling over more lines is very bad, most like virtualizing is not properly working.
Anybody knows, if virtualizing depends on any component or settings of windows 10 system?
Just pasting a part of code with ListView.
Thanks for help.

Update: sorry for disinformation - scrolling is not slow, the scroll unit is not an Item but whole Page (maybe more then page). So visual effect of scrolling is bad.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"  Margin="0,-23,0,0"  x:Name="LogMessagesListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding DataModel.LogMessagesList}" 
    VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item"
    VirtualizingPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Page"
    VirtualizingPanel.CacheLength="1.1"
    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"                      
    VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
    SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionChanged="LogMessagesListView_SelectionChanged" >
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="HandleLogMessageDoubleClick"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding DataContext.Runtime.ColumnWidthHighlight, ElementName=root }"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding DataContext.Runtime.ColumnWidthLevel , ElementName=root}"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding DataContext.Runtime.ColumnWidthDate, ElementName=root}"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding DataContext.Runtime.ColumnWidthTime, ElementName=root}"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding DataContext.Runtime.ColumnWidthProcess, ElementName=root }"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding DataContext.Runtime.ColumnWidthNumber, ElementName=root }"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding DataContext.Runtime.ColumnWidthCategory, ElementName=root }"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Height="14" Width="15" Margin="-14,0,0,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Green" CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="0" Height="14" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Visibility="{Binding IsBookmarked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>
                    <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Yellow" CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="0" Height="14" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Visibility="{Binding IsHighlighted, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>
                    <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="RoyalBlue" CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="0" Height="14" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Visibility="{Binding IsSearchTextHighlighted, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>
                </Grid>

                <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding Level, Converter={StaticResource LevelToImage}}" Width="14" Margin="-2,0,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding LogDate}" Margin="1,0,0,1"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding LogTime}" Margin="1,0,0,1"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding ProcessName}"  Margin="1,0,0,1"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding MessageNumber}" Margin="1,0,0,1"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" Text="{Binding CategoryName}" Margin="1,0,0,1"/>
                <local:TextBlockHighlight Grid.Column="7" Margin="1,0,0,1"
                                                   IsSelected="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"
                                                   Highlighter="{Binding DataContext.DataModel.Highlighter, ElementName=root}"
                                                   LogMessage="{Binding .}"
                                                   DummyTrigger="{Binding MessageInlines}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Possibly some machine specific settings i believe. Can you verify the "Mouse Settings"?

Comment: Mouse settings (advanced also) are on all 3 machines the same. Only a difference between working VM and not working VM is in the list of hardware mouse devices: HID-compliant mouse (on the working VM) and VMware USB Pointing Device (on none working VM). I'll check it later on tonight. Thanks.